# Map both keys and values of a Scala Map

Tags: scala

Scala's `MapLike` trait has a method

```
mapValues [C] (f: (B) ⇒ C): Map[A, C]
```

But I sometimes want a different type:

```
mapKeysAndValues [C] (f: (A, B) ⇒ C): Map[A, C]
```

Is there a simple way to do this which I am missing? Of course, this can be done with a fold.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

`map` method iterates though all `(key, value)` pairs. You can use it like this:

```
val m = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)

val incM = m map {case (key, value) => (key, value + 1)}
```

Comment: If you already have a function `f : (A,B) => (A,C)`, then you can simply `m.map(f.tupled)`. Works with `val f = (x: String, y: Int) => (x, y+1)` but strangely the repl complains if I define `f` equivalently with `def`.

Comment: what does the keyword `case` achieve here?

Comment: @Omnipresent `{case (key, value) => ...}` is just a pattern-matching in this case. Instead of providing a function to a `map`, I giving it a partial function.

Comment: Note: `case` will let you put types in it's pattern, but this is not safe as it could create a runtime error (because it's just a pattern match). Meanwhile, if you ever change the structure of the collection underneath the `map` function so that there are too few or too many objects to interpret as `(key, value)`, then once again, I expect you'd get a runtime error. :(

Answer (score 9):

What about this code:

```
val m = Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two")
def f(k: Int, v: String) = k + "-" + v
m map {case (k, v) => (k, f(k, v))}
```

Which produces:

```
 Map(1 -> 1-one, 2 -> 2-two)
```

This can be packaged into utility method:

```
def mapKeysAndValues[A,B,C](input: Map[A,B], fun: (A, B) => C) = 
  input map {case(k,v) => (k, fun(k, v))}
```

Usage:

```
mapKeysAndValues(
  Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two"), 
  (k: Int, v: String) => k + "-" + v
)
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as [`MapLike#transform`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/MapLike.html#transform[W,That](f:(K,V)=>W)(implicitbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[This,(K,W),That]):That)?

Answer (score 6):

```
m map (t => (t._1, t._2 + 1))

m map (t => t._1 -> t._2 + 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

With some Scalaz:

```
scala> def fst[A, B] = (x: (A, B)) => x._1
fst: [A, B]=> (A, B) => A

scala> Map(1 -> "Lorem", 2 -> "Ipsum").map(fst &&& Function.tupled(_.toString + _))
res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,java.lang.String] = Map(1 -> 1Lorem, 2 -> 2Ipsum)
```

I like @tenshi's solution better.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a utility class:

```
class MyMapLike[K,V](m:MapLike[K,V,_]){
 def mapKeysAndValues[R](f: (K, V) => R)={
   m.map{case (k,v)=> f(k,v)}
 } 
}
object MyMapLike{
 implicit def maplike2mymaplike[K,V](ml:MapLike[K,V,_]):MyMapLike[K,V]=new MyMapLike(m)

}

import MyMapLike._
Map(1 -> "one", 2 -> "two").mapKeysAndValues(k,v=>v*k)
```

Code not tested but it should work somehow simmilar like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
scala> val m = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2)
val m: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 1, b -> 2)

// Convert to anther map
scala> m.map(kvp => (kvp._1, kvp._2 + 1))
val res1: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(a -> 2, b -> 3)

// Convert to a different Iterable type
scala> m.map(kvp => s"${kvp._1} -> ${kvp._2 + 1}")
val res2: scala.collection.immutable.Iterable[String] = List(a -> 2, b -> 3)
```